# VSCode auto-import not working on multiple entry points

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, package.json

```
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*"
  ],
  "exports": {
    "./common": {
      "import": "./dist/common/index.esm.js",
      "require": "./dist/common/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/types/common/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./server": {
      "import": "./dist/server/index.esm.js",
      "require": "./dist/server/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/types/server/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./client": {
      "import": "./dist/client/index.esm.js",
      "require": "./dist/client/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/types/client/index.d.ts"
    }
  },
```

Given this package.json in my own npm library.
In another project, I could import this manually.

```
import { myType } from @myNpm/my-lib/server
```

But if I didn't import it.

VSCode never showed me the auto-import suggestion on `myType` usage.